# HTML5 input form required

Tags: html

I'm trying to figure out if a html5 input using required needs to have the self closing tag or not.

```
<input id="email_input" type="email" class="mim-text-input" required>
```

versus

```
<input id="email_input" type="email" class="mim-text-input" required />
```

Comment: not sure, though html was prettyloose in it

Comment: There is also required="true" is this a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're OK on both accounts: both are valid.

In the [HTML5 syntax specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) it clearly shows inputs without the trailing slash.

However, either are valid. The trailing slash can be used and is [still considered valid](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag) to allow for easier compatibility between xHTML/HTML4 developments.

You could always run your code through the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org) to be absolutely sure.

All that said, however, there's no promise that browser default behaviors aren't effected differently based on syntax so it's very much a case of *user beware*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/), both of those options are valid HTML5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default it is convention used:

```
<input/> or <input> </ input>,
```

the reason is to indicate the end of the statement.
A tag that has more content inside eg:

```
<textarea> content </ textarea>.
```

A tag that has no content in and often and is defined only by their attributes eg:

```
<input/>.
<input> without </ input>
```

Works, only in HTML5 when a tag that has more content inside, in other HTML previous works because the browser or framework fixes for you. As you can see in the generated source code.

Comment: The html is a markup language that can be validated by an XSD or DTD. When you define "DOCTYPE" is implicitly defining which scheme had used to validate your document and formatting rules which he must obey.